# Best way to optimize nested for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a few nested for loops that work and will append a list of scores. This is currently very slow to run. Are there anyways to easily optimize this and have it run quicker?

```
scores = []
for day in range(0,len(date)):
x = []
for entry in range(0,len(df_new)):
    if df_new['timestamp(America/New_York)'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').iloc[entry] == date[day]:
        for times in range(0,len(time)):
            if df_new['timestamp(America/New_York)'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').iloc[entry] == time[times]:
                x.append(df_new['score'].iloc[entry])
scores.append(x)
```

[!Here is a picture of the data frame as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB3mi.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB3mi.png)

Comment: what is `time`, also share a sample dataframe as code

Comment: post the dataframe as code not a picture

Comment: the data frame is being imported through an excel sheet. I use 'pd.read excel' to import.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently calling the method `df_new['timestamp(America/New_York)'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` alot of times inside your nested loops, which means that you will have to fetch that data ALOT of times.

What you could do is to store the value from `df_new['timestamp(America/New_York)'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` in a variable before the loops, and then just call for that variable instead, since it now contains the data you need.

Something like this

```
data_frame = df_new['timestamp(America/New_York)'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

for entry in range(0,len(df_new)):
    if data_frame.iloc[entry] == date[day]:
        for times in range(0,len(time)):

etc. etc.
```

Don't think it will improve TOO much, but a bit atleast!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for loops, you can create two boolean masks for each condition and then index your original dataframe using `&` between the two masks. An example is shown below.

```
print(df)
                   ts  score
0 2021-09-16 11:45:00   88.6
1 2021-09-16 11:48:00   92.3
2 2021-09-30 11:45:00   44.5
3 2021-09-30 12:45:00   55.4

print(dates)
['2021-09-16']

print(times)
['11:45:00', '11:48:00']

mask1 = df["ts"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').isin(dates)
mask2 = df["ts"].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').isin(times)

df.loc[mask1 & mask2]
                   ts  score
0 2021-09-16 11:45:00   88.6
1 2021-09-16 11:48:00   92.3
```